# How to run a jar file with node.js child_process API?

Tags: java, javascript, node.js

I tried to run a jar file on nodejs but it threw out a following error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile /home/example/Applications/example.jar
```

This is the following code that I have in my test.js:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;
child = exec('/usr/bin/java -jar ~/Applications/example.jar',
  function (error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if(error !== null){
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

I ran my test.js with nodejs in this command but received the error above:

```
node test.js
```

Is there any mistake that I made with my code? I am not sure why it is throwing an error at this point.

Comment: try doing this: console.log(require("fs").existsSync("~/Applications/example.jar")?"its there":"its not there"); to figure out if the jar file actually is on that path or not.

Comment: I'd be curious how to best tie the output from the java process to the node process. Should the java process just write to a file and the node process read the file? How does the java process notify node?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

remove `.jar` from `exec();`

java will find the jar file without `.jar` when using the `-jar` argument. else its like.. searching for `filename.jar.jar`

special snowflake macos requires the `.jar` and does not work if you omit it.
(thanks to Gʀɪᴍ) [he also created a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54333776/calling-a-jar-file-in-node-js-with-child-process-do-i-need-the-jar-extension)

Comment: It became this: child = exec('/usr/bin/java -jar ~/Applications/example',
but it still throws the same error.

Comment: is your jar file really at that location?

Comment: Thanks I guess that was my problem. Didn't write location properly.

Comment: This answer is incorrect on the Mac. The `.jar` has to be included or the error will result.

Comment: @Gʀɪᴍ who knows how it was back in 2012 when i wrote this answer. but good to know. i'll add a notice

Comment: @GottZ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54333776/calling-a-jar-file-in-node-js-with-child-process-do-i-need-the-jar-extension

Answer (score 8):

If you are using it on windows command prompt you can use this code.

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec, child;
child = exec('java -jar C:\\..\\..\\yourjar.jar',
function (error, stdout, stderr){
console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
if(error !== null){
  console.log('exec error: ' + error);
}
});
```

Dont forget the double slaces or else it will be a mess.

Comment: Can I able to run the multiple child process executing jar file  dynamically inspite of checking the total CPU's and using for loop ?