# Use methods of a java librairy .jar in node.js

Tags: javascript, java, node.js

I want to use methods contained in my `.jar` file in `node.js`. Until now I just wanted to execute this `.jar`, so I did it with `child_process`.

I found this thread : [Calling a java method in Node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39041536/calling-a-java-method-in-node-js) with a detailed answer but I'm not quite sure what to chose. Are there more options 3 years later ?

What should I pick I'm kinda lost ?

Comment: You'd *fundamentally* have to use these options. Communicating between different applications and different languages and different *runtimes* mandates it. At best, you might find a library or a tool that streamlines this process but it's going to be the same thing underneath.

Comment: IMO the duplicate is quite extensive, there is nothing to add. And without any exact usecase there is no way for us to judge which works best for you

Comment: Ok, if there is nothing new, its indeed a duplicate. Thanks