# Do I need the JAR extension when a jar file in Node.js with child_process?

Tags: java, node.js, macos, jar

Converting several of my shell scripts to Node, so I can learn Node, in shell I typically run a JAR file with the command:

```
java -jar validate.jar test.json >> results.txt
```

When researching how to run a JAR in Node I ran across "[How to run a jar file with node.js child_process API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892195/how-to-run-a-jar-file-with-node-js-child-process-api)" with the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12892407/1952287) indicating the `.jar` extension is not needed.

Following the advise I did a `npm install child_process` after reading "[How to Create JAR file and Using child_process OR shell script to Execute](https://medium.com/@thammarath014/how-to-create-jar-file-213afc10ce38)"

wrote my my script and received an error which was the same error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile /home/example/Applications/example.jar
```

After stepping through I found that on my Mac the `.jar` extension was required to work properly. I understand the answer is from 2012 and it's 2019 but is the answer incorrect or is it OS dependent to call the extension?

Here is the code I've written:

```
let jarFile     = __dirname + '/validate.jar'
let theFile     = 'test.json'
let outputFile  = 'result.txt'
let runCommand  = '/usr/bin/java -jar ' + jarFile + ' ' + theFile
// return console.log(runCommand)


var exec = require('child_process').exec
child = exec(runCommand, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    if(error !== null) {
        console.log('exec error: ' + error)
    } else {
        console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    }
})
```

The code works fine but before learn how to write to a file I want to understand when calling a JAR file is the extension required or not and is that different depending on the OS? I'm currently using Node v6.12.3.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but for future reference, child_process is a built-in module of node so you do not have to do `npm install child_process`.  The same goes for the other [node APIs](https://nodejs.org/api/).

Comment: ew thanks for that, learned something else

Comment: No problem! I would hate to see some malware get embedded in your code because it called itself child_process.

Comment: You mind explaining what you mean?

Comment: If someone were to create a package on npm or other repo called child_process and you ran `npm install child_process` you download it and embed it into your code.  However, I imagine that the node core library names are protected on npm.  See [this story](https://www.csoonline.com/article/3214624/security/malicious-code-in-the-node-js-npm-registry-shakes-open-source-trust-model.html).

Comment: That linked answer is very dubious. I always use `-jar` with the "full" file name (ending in `.jar`). I can believe that it may work (or may have worked) on some platforms with the extension missing, but why go down that road? It will certainly not fail to work because if the `.jar` is present (I don't believe the part about looking for .jar.jar instead -- That must have been a Star Wars joke)

Comment: The documentation for `java` says it should be `java -jar file.jar`. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html