# How to Executing a java .jar file with parse server?

Tags: java, parse-platform, parse-server

I have java exec .jar file. I want to add this with my backend that is parse server. My MbasS is Sashido and I am using parse server there.
Is there any way to add .jar file in the parse server so that whenever user input details from an android app and then automatically execute and give the output.
With php it is possible and I know that but I want to do with parse.
Please tell me how to add exec jar file and what are the operations I must follow...

Comment: You can probably write a cloud code function to execute the .jar file. Cloud code functions are written in javascript (node.js) though, and you'd need to have java virtual machine installed on your app container. So I think you will have to check with your provider.

Comment: Its a long process right? But is there any other way to do that or can you provide me some link or reference so that I can take a idea.

Comment: You an take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12892195/how-to-run-a-jar-file-with-node-js-child-process-api/12892407